# Declarador de miembro inicializador no válido

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Estoy presentando un problema al querer guardar datos utilizando `Request.Params` me indica como error lo siguiente:

> Declarador de miembro inicializador no válido

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El siguiente es el método que utilizo en mi controlador **HomeController.cs**

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GuardarEncuestaDash()
        {
            int pidm = Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.Name);
            var nombre = EstudianteProfService.ObtenerNombre(pidm);
            var edad = EstudianteProfService.ObtenerEdad(pidm);
            var sexo = EstudianteProfService.ObtenerSexo(pidm);

            EncuestaDASH model = new EncuestaDASH()
            {
                PIDM = pidm,
                Nombre = nombre,
                Matricula = EstudianteProfService.ObtenerMatricula(pidm),
                Sexo = (sexo.Equals("") ? "ND" : sexo),
                Semestre = -1,
                model.RMaterias1 = Request.Params["RMaterias1"]

            };

            return Json("OK");
        }
```

La siguiente es la clase que utilizo en mi modelo

```
public class EncuestaDASH
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int PIDM { get; set; }
        public string Matricula { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Sexo { get; set; }
        public int Edad { get; set; }
        public int Semestre { get; set; }
        public string RMaterias1 { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que deberias poner esa linea por fuera de la declaracion de la variable

```
EncuestaDASH model = new EncuestaDASH()
{
    PIDM = pidm,
    Nombre = nombre,
    Matricula = EstudianteProfService.ObtenerMatricula(pidm),
    Sexo = (sexo.Equals("") ? "ND" : sexo),
    Semestre = -1
};

model.RMaterias1 = Request.Params["RMaterias1"];
```

o en caso contrario usar

```
EncuestaDASH model = new EncuestaDASH()
{
    PIDM = pidm,
    Nombre = nombre,
    Matricula = EstudianteProfService.ObtenerMatricula(pidm),
    Sexo = (sexo.Equals("") ? "ND" : sexo),
    Semestre = -1,
    RMaterias1 = Request.Params["RMaterias1"]
};
```